# How can I get search result exact word like "Objective-C++"?

Tags: feature-request, search, exact-phrase-search

It's pretty hard to searching only pages contain exact word like "Objective-C++".
Search result with double-quotations contains heavy of "Objective-C" results.
Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason the tags page won't work for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags

you can also search within tags as documented at

https://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Thanks. Your advise is helpful. I could find what I want. Also *tag search* is useful too. However please consider about feature like *exact term search* itself which can search with *special characters*. (which I instanced in question)